# Change color text on tab navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I want to change the color the text of the navbar on click

I have this code:

```
$("a.tab").click(function() {
            $("a.tab").css("background-color", "#1F1F1F");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#404040");


            $("p.name_tab").css("color", "#939393");
            $(this).css("color", "white");

        });
```

It change well the background-color of my a balise by not the text inside.

I try this but I need to click again on the text to color it.

```
$("p.name_tab").click(function() {
                $("p.name_tab").css("color", "#939393");
                $(this).css("color", "white");
            });
```

Comment: Can you share a HTML snippet? I'm quite afraid you navigate to some page and you expect magically your clicked `<a>` to change color?! I'm asking because the rule of thumb is simple, if you wish to navigate you use `<a>` if instead you need a button well, then you should use `<button type="button">`

Comment: Also, please don't use `style` from JS, use only `toggleClass("is-active")` and define that `.is-active` class styles in CSS.